# How to get the sentimental statement like positive or negative using stanford nlp sentiment library?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am working with the Stanford nlp sentiment analysis. I have tried this code from one blog but i am not able to get the sentiment values of a statement like "positive" or "negative" or some scores.

Following is the code.

```
public class SemanticAnalysis {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sentimentAnalysis sentiments = new sentimentAnalysis();
        sentiments.findSentiment("Stanford University is located in California. " +
                "It is a great university");
    }

}


class sentimentAnalysis {
    public String findSentiment(String line) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        int mainSentiment = 0;

        if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            int longest = 0;
            Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(line);

            for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                String partText = sentence.toString();
                if (partText.length() > longest) {
                    mainSentiment = sentiment;
                    longest = partText.length();
                }
            }
        }

        if (mainSentiment == 2 || mainSentiment > 4 || mainSentiment < 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly were you expecting this to do? The `sentimentAnalysis` class you have there only processes the sentiment and returns `null` or `""`, and you aren't doing anything with that return value. This code doesn't give any feedback to the user.

Maybe you should run it in a debugger or throw a couple print statements in there so you can figure out what it's doing and find a reasonable return value.

There is plenty of documentation out there you can read to find out what you're looking for. I would be surprised if the [API for the Stanford NLP library](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/overview-summary.html) doesn't tell you everything you needed to know.

Comment: yeah i added the print statement and i was getting scores like 1,2,3 or 4 sometimes. The thing is when i changed my adjective from good to bad or great there was hardly any changes in the score.. it was still giving me score as 2. when i printed the "mainsentiment" variable

Comment: I think the Stanford NLP library needs training before it can be used in any meaningful way. Did you give it any training data beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions I have written,

One for initializing sentiment pipeline and another

function processTextSentiment returns the sentiments classes of all sentences in the string text passed a parameter to this function

For example this below sentence would return "Negative:Negative:":

Whatever the number of iPhones sold when Apple reports first-quarter results, it's likely to be mostly a representation of how well the company was able to ramp up supply during the quarter, given that demand is still outstripping supply with only a few weeks left.
1 great stock to buy for 2015 and beyond
2015 is shaping up to be another great year for stocks.

```
public static void initializeSentiPipeline(){
    tokenizerProps = new Properties();
    tokenizerProps.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
    tokenizer = new StanfordCoreNLP(tokenizerProps);
    pipelineProps = new Properties();
    pipelineProps.setProperty("annotators", "parse, sentiment");
    pipelineProps.setProperty("enforceRequirements", "false");
    sentipipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(pipelineProps);
}
public static String processTextSentiment(String text){
    Annotation annotation = tokenizer.process(text);
    sentipipeline.annotate(annotation);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(32);
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println("  " + sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName.class));
        sb.append(sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.ClassName.class));
        sb.append(':');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well sentiment that you are getting

int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);

is the score... it ranges between 0-4.

I slightly modified the code to give you that positive/negative "score"

```
    int mainSentiment = 0;
    int longest = 0;
    String[] sentimentText = { "Very Negative","Negative", "Neutral", "Positive", "Very Positive"};
    NumberFormat NF = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
    for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
        Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
        int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);

        String partText = sentence.toString();
        System.out.println("Sentence: '" + partText + "' is rather " + sentimentText[sentiment]);

        if (partText.length() > longest) {
            mainSentiment = sentiment;
            longest = partText.length();
        }
    }

    if (mainSentiment == 2 || mainSentiment > 4 || mainSentiment < 0) {
        System.out.println("Overall it was sort of neutral review");
    }
    else if (mainSentiment > 2) {
        System.out.println("Overall we are happy");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Bottom line. We are displeased");
    }
```